# Relocate Dropped TFS Builds

Tags: c#, tfs

I need to move a file share containing TFS builds so I wrote some code that walks through a collection of builds and updates their drop location.  I know the code did *something* because when I debug the code on second run the droplocation now shows the new unc path.  However, when I go into team explorer and click on "drop location" for a build, I'm taken to the old location.

What am I missing?

```
var buildServer = tpc.GetService<IBuildServer>();
                        foreach (var build in buildServer.QueryBuilds(projectName))
                        {
                            string newDropLocation = FixPath(build.DropLocation);
                            string newLogLocation = FixPath( build.LogLocation);

                            build.DropLocation = newDropLocation;
                            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(newLogLocation))
                            {
                                build.LogLocation = newLogLocation;
                            }
                            build.Save();

                            Console.WriteLine("------------");
                            Console.WriteLine(newDropLocation);
                            Console.WriteLine(newDropLocationRoot);
                            Console.WriteLine(newLogLocation);
                        }
```

Comment: FWIW, FixPath is just a helper method that does a string.replace for \\olderserver\share\ and \\newserver\share\

Comment: Do you update the new drop location root?

Comment: IBuildDetail.DropLocationRoot is read only.  DropLocation and LogLocation have setters.

Comment: What you did should suffice. Have you tried after a restart of VS? It could just be a missing refresh.

Comment: That gives me a thought. I wonder if the warehouse needs to be rebuilt. I'll try it on Monday.

Comment: I rebuilt the warehouse and I get the same result.  My code shows that droplocation has been updated but team explorer still resolves the old unc path.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but maybe you need to update / recreate the TFS workspace with the new path locations?

Comment: Did you update both the Build Definitions and the actual Builds?

Comment: Old post.. my 2 cents.. Is `build.Save()` enough? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuildserver.savebuilds(v=vs.100).aspx) seems to suggest you should be calling `IBuildServer.SaveBuilds(updatedBuilds)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this functionality is now built into [Community TFS Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/releases/view/92255). The Community TFS Build Manager has the ability to do search and replace updates on existing builds.